# How to save the patch files for Family Tree Maker (FTM2014)?

Tags: family-tree-maker

I want to archive the patches that were released after the DVDs from a boxed copy of Family Tree Maker (FTM2014).  How can I save a copy of a patch file?

My boxed copy was purchased in December 2015 and the about file shows the following information:

> - 22.0.0.1404
> - Product code 056088F00

Answer (score 4):

The page in Ancestry's Support Center about installing updates is here:

[Family Tree Maker 2014 - Installing Updates](http://help.ancestry.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5588)

Look for this section of the page:

[image]

Right click on the link for the file you want and click "Save Link As" or "Save Target As" (whichever command is correct for the browser you use).

Save the files to a known directory.  After that, you can store them in your preferred format in case you need to re-patch the program after it is no longer available from Ancestry.  You can also print the instructions page on installing the upgrades manually to a PDF.

The files are small enough to fit on a CD-ROM which can be stored with your install disc.  You can also back them up on other media for extra security.

Here are the links that were accessed and working on 17 Dec 2015:

- [32-bit patch (zip)](http://service.familytreemaker.com/OhanaService/Updates/22.0/FTM2014SfxPatch32.zip)
- [32-bit patch (exe)](http://service.familytreemaker.com/OhanaService/Updates/22.0/FTM2014SfxPatch32.exe)
- [64-bit patch (zip)](http://service.familytreemaker.com/OhanaService/Updates/22.0/FTM2014SfxPatch64.zip)
- [64-bit patch (exe)](http://service.familytreemaker.com/OhanaService/Updates/22.0/FTM2014SfxPatch64.exe)